# combining .NET Core 2.2 and 3.0 projects

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two .NET unrelated projects. One is a Model (v. 2.2) and another is Web application (v. 3.0.0-preview7). I didn't have the problem with preview5, but now I have trouble running migrations against 2.2 project.

```
C:\>dotnet ef --help
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.IO.Stream, System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions)'.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Method not found: 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.IO.Stream, System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions)'.
```

As I said, with preview5 I don't have any problem. Is it something that changed between 5 and 7, and I need to make some corresponding changes? I didn't see anything in the release notes. Or it is simply a bug, and I just need to wait until next preview?

I don't get any errors on `dotnet build` or `dotnet run`; only on `dotnet ef` commands

Comment: Iirc they got rid of the standard JSON library in net core 3 and made it a nuget package. The migration docs to 3.0 mention this and which package to use. An alternative is to use the newtonsoft JSON nuget package in both projects.

Comment: unfortunately, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` only exists in 3.0; not in 2.2

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite right, I use it in my 2.1 core project. It may be there's more than one newtonsoft JSON package. I'm not near a pc to check.

Comment: yes - there are a number of Newtonsoft packages. I tried to add `Newtonsoft.Json` (that **exists** in 2.2) and it didn't make a difference. Upgrade page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support mentions `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` - that one only exists in 3.0. Not a big deal; I'll stick with preview5 for now

Comment: Bummer :-( There is a discussion about it [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90)

Comment: Yeah, since it's part of *internal* change that Microsoft mentioned, I don't have any control over it. Not a big deal. I'll stay with preview 5, and try again when the new version comes out. Main question was if I missing anything and if **I** can make it work. *no* is a valid answer :)

Comment: I can`t write the comment but I faced the same issue, but my entities ar in netStandard2.1. So I found the article from microsoft about releasing new Json library
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/
and they talk about https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json I installed it on my .net standard project but it does fix my problem, maybe i am doing something wrong, but you can try to install that nugget, maybe it will fix your problem

Comment: @Ignas - no, didn't work for me, either

Comment: Tried preview 8 - same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to create a `global.json` file with the following content:

```
{
   "sdk": {
      "version": "2.2.402"
   }
}
```

as explained in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)

Answer (score 16):

Okey, so I found the solution problem was that `dotnet ef --version` was not preview 7 in my case it was preview 6 so i updated  `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6` and now it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Ignas. Glad you found a solution to your problem. However, the answer in Stack Overflow is supposed to be to the *original* question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: So it should fix your problem also?

Comment: First, as OP, states, I have preview7 and you had preview6. Second, my model is in .NET Core, and yours - in netStandard2.1(?). Your solution was to upgrade to preview7 that I had to begin with. So, *obviously*, you have a different problem that benefit from different solution.

Comment: as I understand what is written in here https://learn.microsoft.com/lt-lt/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes that they The EF Core command-line tool, dotnet ef, is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK, so could you check the version of  ef command line tool, because my version of  ef nuget was good

Comment: I've seen multiple variants of this problem with the same solution - from Preview 5o to 7 the JSON methods available in the SDK have changed. You can also install the correct SDK from the dotnet github. Ensure that all of your packages and tooling on your machine are on the same versions.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was facing this problem while I was trying to run migration commands